# Service Layer with WebApi

Tags: model-view-controller, service, layer

I am starting to work on a new project so working on laying on the architechture at this moment.
So basically we want to keep a service oriented architecture using MVC web api.
So I had the following structure in mind:

```
Project.Core (All Poco classes)
Proect.Data (All entity framerwork)
Project.Service (All Web API ??)
Project.Web
```

We would be working for the first time on webapi here. So wanted to know how do we intergrate webapi here.

Most of the articles we saw read had created a mvc web application and had selected webapi in that. But we 
were looking to create separate service layer just for webapi. Is this the correct practice to do that or
I am missing something here.
We basically wanted not to have a tight coupling b.w MVC web and web api here. If we create web api as part
of mvc then how can we separately access our web api.

WOuld appreciate inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use the project template provided by Visual Studio. Choose Empty ASP.NET project template and then select Add folders and references for Web API. It will create the folder structure needed/recommended purely for a Web API project without any MVC reference. I generally create a separate project for Data Access and use that from the Web API project.